# Save data directly in a cell

Tags: cells, save

How can I save a custom list of data in this style? I would like to save a large imported file in a cell without reading it again.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple example, if we have:

```
dat = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
icon = Iconize[dat, "Data"];
```

[image]

highlight `Iconize[dat, "Data"]` and select "Evaluate in Place" from the "Evaluation" menu (CMD + Enter on macOS). It should turn the selection into an icon which contains the data. This icon can be directly copied and pasted, and either the icon itself or the symbol I've defined `icon` can be used after evaluating the entire cell with Shift + Enter.

[image]